# Ionic show popup between some time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am simply showing a pop But i need to show popup when user come on 00:00 to 16:00 this time can any please tell how is it possible ?

```
    if(If time is between 00:00 to 16:00){
    let popData:any = {
      'title': 'Alert',
      'sub': 'Your Order Will Be Delivered Between 17:30 & 21:30, You Will Receive SMS Updates When Its On Its Way To You.',
      'img': 'assets/image/popupimage.png',
      'button': 'CLOSE'
      }
    console.log(popData);
    this.presentPopover(popData);
}
```

Comment: Try to put your code inside app.component.ts inside initializeApp function

Answer (score 0):

Inside app.component.ts you can do something like :

```
initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();

  d = new Date();

  if(d.getHours() < 16){
let popData:any = {
  'title': 'Alert',
  'sub': 'Your Order Will Be Delivered Between 17:30 & 21:30, You Will Receive SMS Updates When Its On Its Way To You.',
  'img': 'assets/image/popupimage.png',
  'button': 'CLOSE'
  }
console.log(popData);
this.presentPopover(popData);
}
});
 }
```

Comment: I need solution for inside if statement :P

Comment: can you explain little please ? new Date().getHours() give current hour or total hours ? because not under stand this why 16 ? and gethours

Comment: d = new Date() => gets the current time (Fri Apr 24 2020 17:12:01 GMT+0000 (UTC)). d.getHours() => get the current hour (in this case 17)

Answer (score 0):

```
const hrs1 = new Date().getHours();

    if (hrs1 < 16) {
     let popData:any = {
      'title': 'Alert',
      'sub': 'Your Order Will Be Delivered Between 17:30 & 21:30, You Will 
              Receive SMS Updates When Its On Its Way To You.',
      'img': 'assets/image/popupimage.png',
      'button': 'CLOSE'
  }
console.log(popData);
this.presentPopover(popData);
    }
```

Comment: can you explain little please ?  new Date().getHours() give current hour or total hours ?

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem It will fetch current hours.